# Windows 64 bit does not display folder names

Tags: windows-10, reinstall

I have a strange problem after a fresh reinstall of Windows 10, 64-bit.

Just after the reinstall, everything was working fine, but as soon as I'm trying to install something, like a driver for instance, and restarting the computer, **folders are displayed without their names**.

[image]

I observed that using the "Troubleshooting > Startup repair" tool of Windows makes thef folder names come back (despite the tool tells that the startup repair failed). However the problem is not solved and comes again.

The reinstall of Windows 10 was done using Microsoft's Windows installer downloaded from another PC to an USB key. The original partition scheme (including the recovery partition) was kept unaltered. The partitions were not formated again. Files from the previous installation were moved to "Windows.old" folder.

Any idea where does this problem come from and what should I do?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Sure. That's done.

Comment: Reinstall again. Don’t use Microsoft’s downloader. Simply fake a non-Windows User Agent in your browser to download the ISO. Verify it after downloading.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using the Media Creater Tool to download the Windows ISO (but also not required with the numerous methods to get an ISO)

Answer (score -1):

This happened to several of my computers with Windows 10 Creator Update 1703*, I had to run SFC in safe mode and it resolved the issue.  Hopefully that works for you.

In Safe Mode:
CMD(admin) - SFC /scanow

Comment: By KB1703 do you mean the 1703 feature update, because otherwise KB1703 doesn’t exist.  It’s also unlikely the user is using 1703 given the age of this question

Comment: Poor term usage on my end, I meant Windows Creator Update 1703 not kb1703.

Answer (score -1):

We can try the following way:

[image]

**Source:**

https://www.askvg.com/solution-file-folder-names-are-not-visible-in-windows-explorer/

https://www.wintips.org/solved-missing-file-folder-names-in-windows-explorer/

Comment: I think you missed the problem that's in the question. **All** of the text in Explorer has gone missing, not just the icon names.